# What is meaning of "signature outdoor signage"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The brilliant Coco-Cola signs that dot the skylines the world over are called 'spectaculars'-big, bold Coco-Cola signs that proclaim refreshment to millions of passing customers. From New York to Tokyo, the spectaculars reflect the century old Coco-Cola traditions of **signature outdoor signage**.

What is the meaning of this bold part?

Also, does the phrase '-big, bold Coco-Cola signs...' seem fine as we have already been described that spectaculars are Coco-Cola signs and that is repeating it?

Comment: Did you mean '**[Outdoor signage](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=outdoor%20signage)**' ?

Comment: Did you mean [Coc**a**](http://images.coca-colastore.com/imagesEdp/p96131b.jpg)-Cola?

Answer (score 2):

The definition of signage is "signs collectively".  In this context, signature means "a distinctive pattern, product, or characteristic by which someone or something can be identified."  And outdoors is not within a building.

So the "signature outdoor signage" is the outdoor signs that identify something, in your case, Coca-Cola.

Answer (score 2):

**signature** a distinctive pattern, product, or characteristic by which someone or something can be identified
-- New Oxford American Dictionary

**outdoor signage** is just referring to the use of outdoor signs, advertisements

So it's a characteristic/distinctive outdoor sign for Coca-Cola.